# TensorFlow: prediction not working properly

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having a few issues with the model that I've made.

1) Sometimes the prediction returns an array of 0s (But that might be normal).

2) If I repeat the prediction multiple times (using loops) I always get the same result.

3)  Strangely enough, if I stop the program and rerun it, the prediction changes (point 2 still applies).

4) The results are wrong. I insert the same exact query as the training (the response predicted is correct while training), but I get a very different response.

Now, the weird thing is that while training I can see that it is improving and that it is working fine.

Here is the piece of code that displays the correct results (training):

```
decoder_prediction = tf.argmax(decoder_logits, 2) # This line isn't actually here, I put it here to give context
saver.save(sess, MODEL_LOCATION)
fd = next_feed()
predict_ = sess.run(decoder_prediction, fd) # fd stands for feed_dict. This provides {encoder_inputs: .., encoder_inputs_lenghts: .., decoder_targets: ..}
for i, (inp, pred) in enumerate(zip(fd[encoder_inputs].T, predict_.T)): # This is useless but I did not change it as I dont quite understand it (the zip(fd...) part)
    index = random.randint(0, len(fd[encoder_inputs].T)-1) # This is used to pick a random query/prediction
    print('     sample {}'.format(i + 1))
    print('     Query                  > {}'.format(batch_to_words(fd[encoder_inputs].T[index]))) 
    print('     Predicted Response     > {}'.format(batch_to_words(predict_.T[index])))
    if i >= 2:
        break
```

And this is the part that I'm having trouble with (prediction):

```
saver.restore(sess, MODEL_LOCATION)
batch__ = []
query = get_formatted_sentence(sentence)
batch__.append(words_to_batch(query))
batch, batch_len = batch_method(batch__)
for x in range(0,10): # This is the loop I was talking about
    prediction = sess.run(decoder_prediction, feed_dict={encoder_inputs: batch, encoder_inputs_length: batch_len}) # Notice that here I do not give decoder_targets ( If I understand them correctly they are the 'wanted' result. In this case I have no 'wanted' result, I just want to get a prediction
    print(prediction.T)
    print(batch_to_words(prediction.T[0]))
```

That's it. I don't know why this happens. Any help is appreciated. I've also included the other methods for even more context.

---

This is next_feed():

```
def next_feed():

    encoder_inputs_, encoder_input_lengths_ = batch_method(batches_query)
    decoder_targets_, _ = batch_method(
        [sequence + [EOS] + [PAD] for sequence in iter(batches_response)]
    )
    #print(encoder_inputs_)
    #print(encoder_input_lengths_)
    return {
        encoder_inputs: encoder_inputs_,
        encoder_inputs_length: encoder_input_lengths_,
        decoder_targets: decoder_targets_,
    }
```

And this is batch_method:

```
def batch_method(inputs, max_sequence_length=None):
    """
    Args:
        inputs:
            list of sentences (integer lists)
        max_sequence_length:
            integer specifying how large should `max_time` dimension be.
            If None, maximum sequence length would be used

    Outputs:
        inputs_time_major:
            input sentences transformed into time-major matrix
            (shape [max_time, batch_size]) padded with 0s
        sequence_lengths:
            batch-sized list of integers specifying amount of active
            time steps in each input sequence
    """

    sequence_lengths = [len(seq) for seq in inputs]
    batch_size_ = len(inputs)

    if max_sequence_length is None:
        max_sequence_length = max(sequence_lengths)

    inputs_batch_major = np.zeros(shape=[batch_size_, max_sequence_length], dtype=np.int32)  # == PAD

    for index, seq in enumerate(inputs):
        for j, element in enumerate(seq):
            inputs_batch_major[index, j] = element

    # [batch_size, max_time] -> [max_time, batch_size]
    inputs_time_major = inputs_batch_major.swapaxes(0, 1)

    return inputs_time_major, sequence_lengths
```